# Can't get the proper URL in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get something like this:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "url": {
        "small": "http://website/images/image.jpg",
        "large": "http://website/images/image.jpg"
    }, 
}]
```

My code is:

```
 <?php
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('SITE_ROOT', "www.website.net/images/");


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','test','test','test');
$sql="SELECT * FROM images";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response=array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $turl = SITE_ROOT.$row['id'].".jpg";
 $url = str_replace("\/", "\\", $turl);
 $json_Array[] = array('id'=>$row[id],'url'=>array('small'=>$url.$row[src],'large'=>$url.$row[src]));
}

echo(json_encode($json_Array));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But after JSON Encoding, this is what I get:

```
[{
"id":"1",
"url":{
     "small":"www.website.net\/images\/1.jpg",
     "large":"www.website.net\/images\/1.jpg"
      }
 },
 {"id":"2",
"url":{
     "small":"www.website.net\/images\/2.jpg",
     "large":"www.website.net\/images\/2.jpg"}
}]
```

I want the URL like www.website.net/images/1.jpg.
I even tried using:

```
 $turl = SITE_ROOT.$row['id'].".jpg";
 $url = str_replace("\/", "\\", $turl);
```

But still getting those /.
Any kind of help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: JSON escapes some characters in the JSON string. It will decode back to the values you expect

Comment: Any suggestions on overcoming that? @JimL

Comment: See @JimL second sentence!

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `json_encode()` escapes slashes. If you don't want that, pass the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option as the 2nd parameter. It is available since PHP 5.4.0.

Example:

```
echo(json_encode($json_Array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ));
```

For more information, see [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score -1):

Try doing something as this

```
    function request($query){
    $data = array();
    $index = 0;
    if($r = mysqli_query(self::$conn, $query)){
        while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
            $data[$index] = $row;
            $index++;
        }
        return array("request"=>$r, "rows"=>json_decode(json_encode($data), true));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OP's coding. This achieves nothing that would help the OP with his quesiton